# Customise radio button with sprite images

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to customize radio buttons with sprite images, also wanted the description of the element to be displayed within div element at the bottom with respect to the selection made using radio buttons, here is the code that I have worked on so far, can someone help me fix this:

```
<div class="radioForm" ng-controller="radiobuttons">
    <label ng-repeat="navEle in navigationList">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selected" name="navigationList" ng-value="navEle.name">
      <i class="custom-radio-label {{navEle.name.toLowerCase()}}"></i>
      <span>{{navEle.name}}</span>
    </label>
    <div class="showDescription">

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to js fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/p82f1tuw/3/

Comment: Where's your CSS? Please add it to the JSFiddle.

Comment: radio buttons cannot be customize, you will need to simulate them. So basically hide the default ones and write your own. and then take the value from the one you wrote and assign to the default ones. You will need a little bit of javascript(jquery) here too.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kuruvudole/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Please find the modified code with required css applied to it, I wanted the message to be displayed in the "showDescription" element upon radio button select. Also I wanted to hide the radio button and keep alive its functionality of selecting the option by clicking on its respective icon.